# git line ends redux - Mac OS git with contributions for Windows user

Tags: windows, macos, git, line-endings, atlassian-sourcetree

I do development on Mac OS X. I have a user who is contributing code with CRLF line endings. He currently does not use git. I create a branch, then switch my working tree to it. I copy his file into the working tree. When I try to stage the file, I receive the error `fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in pcb-gcode.ulp.`
I've been through endless posts and tried suggestions (such as .gitattributes & git reset) and the only solution seems to be to use `sfk` or similar to change the line endings when I get the file from him.

Is there a way to have git change his CRLF line ends to LF when staging and committing, and use LF if I checkout the branch to my working tree? It seems that there would be an option to have git just recognize a line ending as a line ending and give me what is appropriate for my OS when I check it out.

```
git config --global -l (excerpt)
core.autocrlf=input
core.safecrlf=true

git config --local -l
(nothing relevant)
```

I'm using SourceTree and the remote repo is hosted on Assembla, in case that is pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try new (1.7.2+) `core.eol`

> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files
>   that have the text property set. Alternatives are 'lf', 'crlf' and
>   'native', which uses the platform's native line ending. The default
>   value is native

And don't use buggy and not-obvious `core.autocrlf`