# Crossplatform programming in Git

Tags: git, cross-platform, eol

I am having some trouble with the already well known EOL problem and Git. I usually work with two machines:

- M1 (Work): Windows 7 and Netbeans + VMWare + Debian as a local server.
- M2 (Home): Mac OS and Netbeans + Parallels + Samba + Debian as a local server.

I started this project with Windows. I configured my Mac this weekend and when I cloned the project, all files ara shown as "modified". I've already seen many posts and read the official git article ([Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#platform-linux)) about this problem. But I am still having some questions:

- When I work with Windows, I figure that all files have CRLF end of line... Even if I made the git pull through ssh (then Linux writes the files on Windows)?
- In M2, when I clone the entire project, it is supposed that Git changes automatically all the EOL according to Git Global config or `.gitattributes` file. When I edit these files by Netbeans through Samba in Mac OS is again the EOF changed?

So, it is clear that Git has to auto-manage the EOL because I'm working with different platforms, but I don't know how exactly make the approach. It would be good as well to know more in deep in which way Git applies this autocrlf on the different commands (pull, commit, checkout, etc...).

Comment: I've never had much luck letting Git handle my line endings. On Windows, I configure it to "check out as-is, commit as-is" (which is not the default) and rely on my editor to use Unix-style line endings.

Comment: +1 for @Chris's comment. Rely on the editors to manage the line endings for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355458/git-line-ends-redux-mac-os-git-with-contributions-for-windows-user + some answers on theme from @VonC